# How can I fix iOS simulator rotation?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios-simulator

In my app I have set the storyboard to allow only horizontal and inverted horizontal rotations. I have a single view controller scene with a single UIView subclass in it. Everything worked fine, until I deleted the scene in the IB editor and tried to remake it. I changed no code at all, but now, whenever I run my app in the iOS Simulator, I see this:

[image]

Whereas previously I'd see a horizontal iPad screen with the status bar at the top and my grid filling the screen.

`self.frame.size.width` gives me 1024 and `self.frame.size.height` returns 748 in `awakeFromNib`, so my view thinks it has the right size and orientation.

Thinking I'd made a mistake, I deleted the storyboard entirely and made a brand new one, again with a single view controller scene containing a single instance of my UIView subclass. The same thing happens: a weird sideways iPad.

So, what have I done wrong?

EDIT: A Bit more testing reveals that the view itself is also rotated. In other words, the top left origin (0, 0) is actually in the bottom left of that picture above.

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the screen autorotation to:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || 
    (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

You can delete this later if needed.  A similar instance as your happened to me.  I changed no code, then Storyboard decided to change the orientation of my app.  Simply limiting the interface in the code fixed it in storyboard.  As I said, once fixed, you can delete the code if you don't need it.
Good luck!

Comment: I had actually resolved this a while back, and this did turn out to be the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may just have your device rotated in the simulator.  After you have hit the `run` button if you go to `Hardware > Rotate Left` it should fix your starting orientation and then it will start up in the correct orientation next time you run.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the new created storyboard as your "Start Storyboard" in your project?

Comment: Yes. It's set as the Main Storyboard. I don't believe it would have shown anything at all if not.